# Printing Out File Names that are Different

Tags: java, arrays

My code below works and the logic works. However, I want to print out the names of the actual files that are not the same in both folders, which are held in the arrays of `fileNames1` and `fileNames2`. I have been searching for the answer with no solution. I am just getting back into the groove with Java after being away form it a while. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class nameCompare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path1 = "C:/Users/hoflerj/Desktop/test"; 
        String path2 = "C:/Users/hoflerj/Desktop/test2"; 

        File folder1 = new File(path1);
        File folder2 = new File(path2);

        File[] listOfFiles1 = folder1.listFiles(); 
        File[] listOfFiles2 = folder2.listFiles(); 

        ArrayList<String> fileNames1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> fileNames2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles1.length; i++) 
        {

            if (listOfFiles1[i].isFile()) 
            {
                fileNames1.add(listOfFiles1[i].getName());//wow
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles2.length; i++) 
        {

            if (listOfFiles2[i].isFile()) 
            {
                fileNames2.add(listOfFiles2[i].getName());//seriously wow
            }
        }


        for ( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
        {
            if (fileNames1.equals(fileNames2) )
            { 
                System.out.println("Files names are the same");
            }

            else if (fileNames1 != fileNames2 )
            { 
                System.out.println("Files names are not equal");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What are you looking for in the outputs exactly?

Comment: `fileNames1 != fileNames2` is not how to compare strings. put a `!` in front of the first test you made , e.g. `!fileNames1.equals(fileNames2)` to test the opposite of that test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've created and populated both the lists, use the following code :-

```
for(String fileName : fileNames1)
{
 if(!fileNames2.contains(fileName))
   {
     System.out.println(fileName + " is not in both");
   } 
 else
   {
     System.out.println(fileName + " is in both the lists");
   }
}
```

What this code does is that for each `fileName` in the first `ArrayList` it checks if the second `ArrayList` contains the same file name or not, and prints the output accordingly.

Comment: eclipse suggest this for(String fileName : fileNames1). is that correct?

Comment: This will miss items in list 2 that are not in list 1. So if fileNames2 contains all fileNames1 plus some, it will say nothing but "file in both lists"

Comment: So how do i get past this error in eclipse? there is a red line under fileNames1

Comment: @JonathanHofler indeed Eclipse is right and there was an error in my answer. I have edited it to what it should be now and I apologise for my mistake!

Comment: Also, I agree with what Tezra says. My solution has to be implemented twice. A more elegant solution would involve the use of a Hash structure to optimise efficiency. But, since I read that you're just getting back into the java groove, and figured that your data structure is relatively small, I did not suggest a Hash implementation. But, if you do implement a solution with Hash, then that's always the best one when you're dealing with "contains" type situations.

Comment: Thanks for getting back with me I have been implemented this twice and it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and elegant way to do this is:

```
    List<String> commonFiles= new ArrayList<String>(fileNames1);
    commonFiles.retainAll(fileNames2);       

    Set<String> uniqueFiles = new HashSet<String>(fileNames1);
    uniqueFiles.addAll(fileNames2);
    uniqueFiles.removeAll(commonFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare every element of both the arrays.

```
for( int i = 0; i <= listOfFiles1.length - 1; i++)
{
    for( int j = 0; i <= listOfFiles2.length - 1; i++)
{
    if (listOfFiles1[i].equals(listOfFiles2[j]) )
        { 
            System.out.println("Files names are the same");
        }

        else if (listOfFiles1[i]!= listOfFiles2[j])
        { 
            System.out.println("Files names are not equal");
        }

}

}
```